# How to make DIV draggable and VISIBLE accross the whole body with this HTML structure? JQuery

Tags: jquery, draggable

```
<body>
 <div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <div id="color_submenu">
      <div class="colors" style="background-color:red;"></div>
      <div class="colors" style="background-color:green;"></div>
      <div class="colors" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    </div>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="container>

   .....content....

 </div>
</body>
```

I want the div's with the .color to be draggable across the whole window. However when I do:

```
$('.color').draggable({containment: "window"});
```

The div does become draggable across the whole body but it's not visible after it goes out of the div #color_submenu. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to specify zIndex value? like below:

```
$('.colors').draggable({zIndex:1000}); // you can set zIndex value greater then other container.
```